# Bash gotcha: cat FILE | while read A ; do ... exit .. done

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I had a long pause in writing bash script, and I got trapped again:

```
cat FILE | while read SPID ; do
        if ls $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                echo Error: some files exist in the directory $ODIR:
                ls -la $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv
                exit
        fi
done
```

I happily assumed the `exit` will exit the whole bash script, as it should, but as it is in pipe, it probably exits just the sub-process dispatched to run `while` part.

I already forgot how to easily workaround this. Please remind me! :-)

**EDIT: ** now I have changed the code (for some other reason) to use variable instead, and I am looking for workaround for this:

```
EXIST="no"
cat FILE | while read SPID ; do
        if ls $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                echo Error: some files exist in the directory $ODIR:
                ls -la $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv
                EXIST="yes"
        fi
done
```

but I guess this is the same case, I need the inside of the loop to be run with the same shell as runs the whole script.

Comment: Why do you think your first implementation isn't working? I did a simplified version and `exit` exits the script. So perhaps something else is going awry, not the `exit`. (Your second implementation doesn't check the value of `$EXIST`.)

Comment: @lurker did you run it in the script? And did the `exit` finish the whole script? Put `echo I AM STILL RUNNING` after the while loop to check this.

Comment: Yes, I ran it in a script, but I see what you mean now. The while loop is exited (along with the piped command) but not the entire script.

Comment: istead of ls you could [ -f $ODIR/*${SPID}*.csv ] and use process substitution instead of pipe. also beware of spaces in unquoted file names

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: you wouldn't have this problem with `while ....; do ...; done < FILE`.

Answer (score 7):

From [bash manual pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell [...]

The sides of `|` are run in a subshell. Environment changes are not visible from the subshell in the parent shell.

```
( exit; )                   # exits the subshell only
: | exit                    # exits the subshell only
a=1; ( a=5; ); echo $a      # prints 1, a=5 is executed in a subshell
a=1; : | a=5;  echo $a      # prints 1, a=5 is executed in a subshell
```

Pipe the file to stdin to execute the `while` loop in parent shell context.

```
 while IFS= read -r spid; do
    ...
 done <file
```

Note that UPPER CASE variables are by convention reserved for environment exported variables, like `IFS`, `LINES`, `COLUMNS`, `PWD`, `UID` etc. Prefer to use lower case variables.

Recommended reads: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) and [how to read a file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: yeah the `while ... done < FILE`, that's it :-) Although it feels a bit creepy, to have the `< FILE` after `done` :-) First I tried `while read  SPID < FILE ; ...` and it didn't work.

Comment: `while` is a command like any other. You redirect its standard input from `FILE`, and `read` inherits *its* standard input from the loop. This way, the file is only opened once, and `read` is able to read a different line each time it is executed.

Answer (score 2):

A common workaround for the variable assignment is to increase the scope with {}:

```
cmd | { 
    while read spid; do var=assigned-value-$spid; break; done;
    : here, var retains the value assigned in the while loop
}
: now var retains whatever value it had (or is unset) before the pipeline
```

To "elevate" the exit, it is common to do:

```
if ! cmd | { while read spid; do ... if ... exit 1; ... done; ... exit 0; }; then
   exit
fi
```

If the subshell exits non-zero, the entire shell will exit.

Comment: If you exit, then you'll never get to the lines after the while loop.

Comment: even within the `{ }` in the pipe? Isn't the `{ }` in the pipe run in another subshell?

Comment: The point is that the code inside the `{}` is all running in one subshell, so that assignments within the while loop persist until the `}`

Comment: exactly, so exit will probably not exit the whole script but just the subshell, right? that was my point ;-)

Comment: @TMS Oh, right, I got sidetracked into thinking the question is about the variable assignment.  I'll mention one other common technique for exiting the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could exit with a code in your sub-shell, then check it's exit code when the `while` loop is done:

```
cat FILE | while read SPID ; do
    if ls $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo Error: some files exist in the directory $ODIR:
        ls -la $ODIR/*$SPID*.csv
        exit 1
    fi
done

# Exit script if exit code from the previous command is 1
if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
    exit
fi
```

I think @KamilCuk's answer for refactoring this as `while ... done < file` is preferable in this case. But the above shows an alternative for the sub-shell process, in case you have a lot more going into the `stdin` than the simple `cat` of a file.

Comment: Or, just `if !  cmd | while ...; do ...;  exit 1; done; then exit 1; fi`